# Internet Explorer puts hashes in href with jQuery Address

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, pushstate, jquery-address

I'm looking for a good pushstate jquery plugin to work with ajax-json (and php's mod_rewrite when js is turned off) and found jQuery Address. I like it a lot since it's well documented and easy to work with. (I never really figured out history.js) I noticed however that the great internet explorer (9) puts hashes there in the href field. It's doing it in the example as well: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/contact I've tested other browsers but you can only see this with the great internet explorer. Any way around this?

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer 9 [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) the History API. Instead, applications that make use of these api's have to fallback to `onhashchange` functionality, which utilizes the fragment of the location to replicate similar functionality in less-capable browsers.

What you're seeing is expected; [Internet Explorer 10+ supports this newer functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and thus doesn't require adding `/#` to the url to record and preserve the state-history. Internet Explorer 9 does not support the History API, and thus provisions have to be made.

You mentioned history.js, which extends support for methods like `history.pushState` into non-HTML5 browsers. On this projects [GitHub page](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) you can see a few examples of how urls will appear in newer browsers, vs how they will appear in older browsers. As expected, the pattern you're experiencing now is produced there as well.

Although there is a fragment in your url when viewed in Internet Explorer 9, note that this doesn't reflect the requested path on your server. Note the address requested entered into the browser, and the actual request in the Network tab to the server:

[image]

#### Resolving the 404

The reason you were getting a 404 in IE9 is because in browsers that don't support the HTML5 History API, jQuery.address will re-navigate to whatever state you provide in your setup. So there is the initial request that is passed to your server when you type in the url. This address is handled by mod_rewrite and your `RewriteRules` determine the initial content to be loaded.

When your initial content is loaded, and jQuery.address is setup, a new navigation even takes place to your setup path. In your case, this was `/posters`. Unfortunately, you didn't have any `RewriteRules` in place to provide content to `/posters`, so the end result was a 404. Again, this *only* happened in IE9 since IE9 doesn't support the History interface.

This can be confirmed by again visiting the Network tab of the F12 Developer Tools and capturing the data. With that tab opened, press "Start capturing", and then type in the full path to a product on your cart. You'll notice an initial request to that full path, followed by the loading of several dependencies. Shortly afterwards you will see another navigation event take place to whatever path you provided in `$.address.state`.